# Can NHibernate query for specific children without lazy loading the entire collection?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

When I have an entity object with a one-to-many child collection, and I need to query for a specific child object, is there a feature or some clever pattern I haven't come up with yet to avoid that NHibernate fetches the entire child collection?

Example:

```
class Parent 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; proteced set; } // generated PK
    public virtual IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; proteced set; }
}

class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; } // generated PK
    public virtual string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; protected set; }
}

// mapped with Fluent

class Service
{

    private readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Service(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    void DoSomethingWithChildrenNamedBob(int parentId)
    {
        using(var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var parent = session.Get<Parent>(parentId);
            // Will cause lazy fetch of all children!
            var childrenNamedBob = parent.Children.Where(c => c.Name == "Bob"); 
            // do something with the children
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's not the best example because in this case one would probably just query the Child entities directly, but I have encountered situations where I already had a Parent object and needed to traverse specific sub-trees through it.

Comment: Did you try loading the Child you're after and including the parent?

Comment: Of course I could do that in this specific situation. Hence, not the best code example, like I said. But it doesn't answer my general question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no. Longer answer: you can make it do this, with some sleight of hand.

Rippo's answer above shows how you would do it the 'proper' NHibernate way (whether it's with Linq or QueryOver or HQL doesn't really matter - the point is you have to step outside the parent -> child relationship to do a query). You can take this a step further and disguise this behind a façade. But to do so, you have to remove the mapped relationship entirely and replace it with a query at all times. You'd take out the Parent -> Children mapping, but leave the Child -> Parent mapping intact; then re-write the property on Parent to look like this:

```
public virtual IQueryable<Child> Children
{
    get
    {
        // somehow get a reference to the ISession (I use ambient context), then
        return session.Query<Child>().Where(c => c.Parent == this);
    }
}
```

Now, when you use `Parent.Children` you get back a queryable collection, so you could then write

```
IEnumerable<Child> childrenNamedBob = parent.Children.Where(c => c.Name == "Bob");
```

The only way you could do this and preserve the mapping is to amend NHibernate's collection objects (or inject your own). Diego Mijelshon (who is around these parts) wrote a spike of exactly that, adding IQueryable support to NHibernate collections so you could do

```
IEnumerable<Child> childrenNamedBob = parent.Children.AsQueryable().Where(c => c.Name == "Bob");
```

But from what I can see, this never went any further and there's no apparent plan to add this capability to NH. I have run Diego's code and it does work, but obviously it's not production quality and hasn't been tested, and I don't think it's ever been officially 'released' even as a private patch.

Here's the link to the discussion on the NH issue tracker: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2319

I believe NH should support this out of the box, as it's a natural way for most .NET devs to want to interact with pretty much anything enumerable, now that we have Linq, and not being able to do it without the side-effect of loading an unbounded collection into RAM sucks. But the traditional NH model is session -> query and that's what 99% of people use.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I couldn't agree more that NH should support this out of the box, it's a pity that it doesn't. Since I definitely don't want to make my entities aware of NH, I'll have to deal with it and try to query the way Rippo pointed out when possible.

Comment: I agree, it's a trade-off. Persistence-agnostic entities are a good thing. An AOP approach might be worth considering - it's something I've thought about before.

Comment: Yes, that could work, but that adds another layer of complexity, and NH is complex enough as it is. I think it's just not worth it.

Comment: @chris - I know this is over a year later, but the extensions Neil was talking about was [Nhibernate.CollectionQuery](https://github.com/diegose/NHibernate.Diegose). I currently have a fork that has some refactorings to prevent exceptions being thrown (when I started using it). You can install the original from NuGet or my fork on [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/feed/thecloudlesssky/package/NHibernate.CollectionQuery)

Comment: Oo, nice. I shall have to try that out!

Answer (score 3):

I asked the same question on NHusers a few weeks ago and didn't get an answer so I suspect the answer is `you will always get all the parents children and then perform a in-memory filter`. In many cases this might be the correct way in seeing it.

In your case I would rewrite the query to be:-

```
var childrenNamedBob = session.Query<Children>()
  .Where(w => w.Parent.Id == parentId && w.Name == "Bob");
```

Then simply to get parent (if childrenNamedBob has results) you could call:-

```
   var parent = childrenNamedBob.First().Parent;
```

or as you rightly pointed out:-

```
var parent = session.Get<Parent>(parentId);
```

Comment: I feared as much. I'll probably just have to deal with it. Unless something else comes up in the next few days, I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: BTW, if I needed a reference to the parent, I would still explicitly query it with session.Get<Parent>(parentId), even after querying for the children with your query. First, it's at least just as efficient than childrenNamedBob.First().Parent thanks to the session cache, and second, I don't have to check / make assumptions whether the query for the children has results.

Comment: Yes, it will issue the same query and your version most likely makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can now do that with NHibernate 5 directly without specific code !

See https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/releasenotes.txt

```
Build 5.0.0
=============================

** Highlights
...
    * Entities collections can be queried with .AsQueryable() Linq extension without being fully loaded.
...
```